# Could not find activerecord-postgis-adapter-5.0.0 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, activerecord, postgis

Error when pushing to Heroku `Could not find activerecord-postgis-adapter-5.0.0 in any of the sources`. 
Using PostGIS in development and production. 
Gemfile:
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

ruby '2.4.0'
gem 'bundler'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.2'
gem 'pg'
gem 'puma', '3.4'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 3.2.0'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.beta'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.11'
gem 'carrierwave',             '1.1.0'
gem 'leaflet-rails'
gem 'activerecord-postgis-adapter'
gem 'rgeo-geojson'
gem 'leaflet-draw-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails' 
gem 'tether-rails' 
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.1.5'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '1.0.0'
gem 'gon'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2.3'

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.5.1'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.8', '< 3.2'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'rubocop', require: false 
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
  gem 'awesome_print'
  gem 'super_awesome_print'
  gem 'heroku_db_restore'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem "better_errors"
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.1.9'
  gem 'guard',              '2.14.1'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.4.6' 
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '1.0.2'
  gem 'simplecov', :require => false
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

database.yml (edited):

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgis
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
```

Thank you for any suggestions. Is the `activerecord-postgis-adapter` asking for something not needed. https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter.

Problem with stackoverflow. Usually get asked to put in more code. Now can't post because not enough details. Not sure what I should add, so I'll keep typing until the error goes away. I have been able to push this to Heroku in the past, but have have other issues with the postgis-adaptor and maybe it's a recent update that's causing the problem. I don't know where the version number is coming from. The sources part of the Gemfile is a bit of a mystery to me.

Among other things I tried:

`gem uninstall activerecord-postgis-adapter`

```
Select gem to uninstall:
 1. activerecord-postgis-adapter-3.1.2
 2. activerecord-postgis-adapter-4.0.2
 3. activerecord-postgis-adapter-5.0.0
 4. activerecord-postgis-adapter-5.0.1
 5. All versions
```

I selected option 5 and reran `bundle install`. `Gemfile.lock` now `activerecord-postgis-adapter (4.0.4)` but on Heroku push still get `Could not find activerecord-postgis-adapter-5.0.0 in any of the sources`.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `Gemfile.lock` for that Gem, I am guessing you installed it previously (possibly on another system if its checked it) and locked to 5.0.0?

RubyGems does not have a 5.0.0 version of this Gem, so it would seem the author deleted it. https://rubygems.org/gems/activerecord-postgis-adapter

Bundler however will never update your gems automatically (it tracks the version in `Gemfile.lock`), but you can use `bundle update` or `bundle update activerecord-postgis-adapter` to tell it to do so.

See http://bundler.io/man/bundle-update.1.html

Comment: `activerecord-postgis-adapter (5.0.0)
      rgeo-activerecord (~> 5.1)` 
was in `Gemfile.lock`. I deleted the file and ran `bundle update` and still shows the same. I'll try to read the link although it's a bit over my head. So is some other gem asking for this specific version? 

I tried `bundle update --conservative` and still got `Using activerecord-postgis-adapter 5.0.0` in the listing.

Thank you for your prompt answer

Comment: `bundle update activerecord-postgis-adapter` results in 5.0.0.

Comment: I edited out the ` (5.0.0)` from `activerecord-postgis-adapter (5.0.0)` in the Gemfile.lock (no doubt a no-no) and when pushing to Heroku, still get the error  `Could not find activerecord-postgis-adapter-5.0.0 in any of the sources`

Comment: I tried (formatting not working-the following is six lines)

    gem uninstall activerecord-postgis-adapter

    Select gem to uninstall:
     1. activerecord-postgis-adapter-3.1.2
     2. activerecord-postgis-adapter-4.0.2
     3. activerecord-postgis-adapter-5.0.0
     4. activerecord-postgis-adapter-5.0.1
     5. All versions

I selected option 5 and reran `bundle install`. `Gemfile.lock` now `activerecord-postgis-adapter (4.0.4)` but on Heroku push still get `Could not find activerecord-postgis-adapter-5.0.0 in any of the sources`.

Comment: It may potentially be another Gem asking for a specific version, normally they will just specific say the major versions they support. The lock file shows such dependencies indented, e.g. `activerecord (5.1.1)` requires `activemodel` and `activesupport` also exactly at 5.1.1, but `arel` is `~> 8.0`.   If a currently active Gem requires somthing not actually available, I guess thats a bug that should be reported to them. Heroku and any other platforms should install exactly what the `Gemfile.lock` you push says (thats the point, not to get accidental updates and break stuff).

Comment: If I'm reading the `Gemfile.lock` correctly no specific version of `pg` or  `activerecord-postgis-adapter` was being requested (I compared the current `Gemfile.lock` to one from a previous commit). But you're saying that Heroku may not have a current version?

Comment: hmm, not sure then.Could you provide both the complete `Gemfile` and the `Gemfile.lock` (remember to rerun bundle after you make any changes to `Gemfile`)?

Comment: For Heroku, im saying if you didn't checkin/push `Gemfile.lock`, then Heroku might install different things (and more importantly, things you didn't test!)

Comment: I don't think that was the problem. I think it had to do with the pg version, and something requiring v5 of `activerecord-postgis-adapter` while now it's v4.0.4

Comment: Well still shouldn't happen and the lock file should show it. If a current version of the `pg` gem is trying to use 5.0.0 which doesn't exist, thats a bug to report to the `pg` maintainers.

Answer (score 0):

I made two changes and am not sure which was the key. I changed `gem 'pg', '~>0.18.4'` by removing the version constraint which then lead to v `0.21.0` being installed. I also moved `gem 'rgeo-geojson'` to above `gem 'activerecord-postgis-adapter'` in the Gemfile. Ended up with `activerecord-postgis-adapter 4.0.4` after `bundle update`, which isn't the latest version so still curious how all this works. I suspect the former change is the one that's important. I based these changes on a newer related app that I am working on that did upload to Heroku.